# How can I increase the performance of Ranorex tests?

Tags: ranorex

I'm migrating from MicroFocus Silk to Ranorex. Compared to Silk, the Ranorex tests seem to be slower. How can I improve performance of Ranorex recordings?

Answer (score 1):

In recordings, you often have KeySequences. For those, you have the following options:

- merge KeySequences that have been split into different steps. You can change the split time in Settings/Recorder Defaults.
- reduce the duration of the KeySequence (in step properties)
- reduce the delay before pressing KeySequences (in Settings/Advanced)

If your application does not react on single keypress events, you can also

- use `Set Text` instead of KeySequences

Furthermore you can

- enable Turbo Mode
- disable item logging (you can change the default in Settings / Recorder Defaults)
- disable debugging